# How can I make an automated macro on excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made this macro:

```
Sub clean()
' clean Macro
ChDir "C:\_deletelater\xls"
Workbooks.OpenText filename:="C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.xls", Origin:= _
    437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A1:AD18").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:="DYN", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="WOO", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="MIS", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="BAS", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="BAR", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="DLC", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="SYN", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

I want to just click on my xlsm file and when it opens, I would want the file that gets saved in:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.csv", _
  FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

to get created without me having to press run macro.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the file is set to trusted but you can put code into the ThisWorkbook section behind the scenes that calls the macro when it gets triggered by the workbook being opened.

There's a Microsoft article detailing how to do it... http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/running-a-macro-when-excel-starts-HA001034628.aspx

Comment: The macro code? I am following the steps in the link you sent but I dont see "workbook" above the code window? Sorry this is my first time using this.

Comment: The microsoft article should contain all the VBA required in the section titled **Creating a VBA procedure for the Open event of workbook**